# Not able to clear file Contents

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file which has below data.

```
edit 48
    set dst 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
    set device "Tague-VPN"
    set comment "Yeshtel"
edit 180
    set dst 64.219.107.45 255.255.255.255
    set device "Austin-Backup"
    set comment "images.gsmc.org"
```

I want to copy the commands under edit only if Set device is Austin-Backup.

```
string = 'set device'

word = '"Austin-Backup"'

with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('script.txt', 'w') as newfile:

    for line in oldfile:
        newfile.write(line)
        newfile.write('\n')
        if string not in line:
            pass
        elif string in line:
            if word not in line:
                a = open('script.txt', 'w')
                a.close()

        else:
            pass
```

I am trying to write test file content to new file(script) and if command "set comment "Yeshtel"" is found i want to delete contents in new file. I tried to delete but its not happening. I am new to Python, Can you please tell what is the Prob??

I got to know that reopening the same file in Write mode will clear the contents..

Comment: Can't open file twice ! (write method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you have the same file open twice, once as `newfile` and a second time as `a`. While it should be truncated when you open it as `a` and then close it, the writes you made on `newfile` may still appear if the filesystem had cached them until after the truncated version was written.

I suggest only opening the file once. When you need to truncate it, call the `truncate` method on it.

```
if word not in line:
    newfile.truncate()
```

If you might write more to the file after truncating, you should probably also `seek` back to the start position (e.g. `newfile.seek(0)`). If you're going to be done with the file after truncating it, that step is not needed.

Comment: with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('cript.txt', 'r+') as new:
 for line in oldfile:
  new.write(line)
  new.write('\n')
  if string not in line:
   pass
  elif string in line:
   if word in line:
    print line
    shutil.copy('cript.txt','result.txt')
   elif word not in line:
    new.seek(0,0)
    new.truncate()         now i am getting output in cript.txt but its not getting copied to result.txt...

Comment: It's just about impossible to follow Python code without indentation, so your comment isn't very meaningful. That said, it looks like you're trying to copy a file while it remains open, which will probably not work because of caching.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this

```
temp_lines = []
last_line_was_edit = False
found_keyword = False
keyword = "Austin-Backup"
with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('script.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if last_line_was_edit and temp_lines:
            if found_keyword:
                newfile.writelines(temp_lines)
            temp_lines = []

        if line.startswith("edit"):
            last_line_was_edit = True
        else:
            if keyword in line:
                found_keyword = True
            temp_lines.append(line)
```

Please note that you should not open the file twice. Just use an temporary variable and write only what have to be written